# Form value in a select

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular page like:

```
 catClient: any = [
    [1, 'VALUE1', 'DescriptionValue1', true],
    [2, 'VALUE2', 'DescriptionValue2', true],
  ];
  selectedCategory: string;
  customer = {
    baseTypeIdentifier: '', // if isNewCustomer = false, baseTypeIdentifier will be for example: VALUE1 for BE
  };

    // customer = {
    //  baseTypeIdentifier: 'VALUE1',
    //  };
  isNewCustomer: boolean = true;

  selectCustomerType(newVal) {
    console.log('newVal ', newVal);
    console.log('catCliente ', this.catClient);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.catClient.length; i++) {
      if (newVal == this.catClient[i][0]) {
        this.selectedCategory = this.catClient[i][2];
        console.log('selectedCategory ', this.selectedCategory);
        this.customer.baseTypeIdentifier = this.selectedCategory;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and html:

```
<div>
  <select
    *ngIf="isNewCustomer"
    class="form-control"
    [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
    [(ngModel)]="customer.baseTypeIdentifier"
    (ngModelChange)="selectCustomerType($event)"
    appTab
    placeholder="SelectValue "
    tabIndex="1"
    [disabled]="!isNewCustomer"
  >
    <option value="-1" disabled="">Select Value</option>
    <option
      *ngFor="let cat of catClient"
      name="fieldName"
      ngDefaultControl
      [value]="cat[0] | number"
    >
      {{ cat[1] }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u5egtt?file=src/app/app.component.html

I have a problem here, if isNewCustomer = true I have to choose the value from the select (but I have to select 2 time to appears) while if isNewCustomer = false I should show the value in customer.baseTypeIdentifier  but it doesn't work.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you issue is with the, look at the line which is commented which starts with @@@.

I think by assigning it by the text and not by the value, this should solve your issue

```js
selectCustomerType(newVal) {
    console.log('newVal ', newVal);
    console.log('catCliente ', this.catClient);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.catClient.length; i++) {
      if (newVal == this.catClient[i][0]) {
        this.selectedCategory = this.catClient[i][2];
        console.log('selectedCategory ', this.selectedCategory);
        this.customer.baseTypeIdentifier = newVal;
      }
    }
  }
```

Test [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2kpen4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Mmh ok it seems to be the problem , but If I need this assignment ? I have tried outisde the for but the result is the same

Comment: @Jack23 i've updated my code, you can set the value, just use the newVal instead of the  `this.selectedCategory`, if you're happy with my solution, please upvote and mark this as the answer, thanks

Comment: doing that, removes the issue while keeping the manual setting of the value